# How to write clean python mock code with nested property mock

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have below mock code:

```
mockSuper = mock.MagicMock()
type(mockSuper).role = mock.PropertyMock(
  return_value=mock.MagicMock())
type(mockSuper.role).role = mock.PropertyMock(return_value='Super')
```

What I want is `mockSuper.role.role = "my value"`. But the above code does not look very straightforward. This is my first time using python mock, so I think there should be some better version of this code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this:

```
>>> import unittest.mock
>>> m = unittest.mock.Mock()
>>> m.role.role = "some_value"
>>> m.role.role
'some_value'
```

But I wonder if you really want to stick a string in to the attribute. Maybe it is just enough to run something first and at the end assert.

```
def test():
    mock = Mock()
    mock_role_role = function_returning_mock_role_role(mock)
    assert mock_role_role == mock.role.role
```

If you have a choice left I recommend not testing for law-of-demeter violations - if you test first, for example.